# Mocking DAO object with MockMvc in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-integration, powermockito, mockmvc

I am new to Integration testing. I have Spring Integration application for which I am writing test cases. here is how I am writing test case:
**Activator:**

```
@Service
public class ProdAppActivator { 
    @Autowired
    private ApplicantDAO applicantDAO;
    @Transactional
    public ApplicantDTO prodApp(ApplicantDTO applicant)
            throws TechnicalException, BusinessException {

        applicantDAO.updateApp(applicant);
        
        return application;
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class AcctImplTest extends AbstractTest {    
    @MockBean 
    private ApplicantDAO applicantDAO;

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void testProdApp() throws Exception {
        ProdAppRequest appRequest = getProdAppRequest();
        mvc.perform(post("/baseurl/applicant").headers(getHeaders()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapToJson(appRequest)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

**AbstractTest:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:group/deposit/svc/product-application-context-test.xml" })
@WebMvcTest
//@IfProfileValue(name ="profiles.active", value ="Integration")
public abstract class AbstractTest {
    
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    protected void setUp() {
        setCMD();
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();        
    }
}
```

I have 2 issues:

1. This activator has a method with @Transactional annotation. I am not sure why but because of this annotation my test getting failed and giving error as:

```
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession(HibernateTransactionManager.java:711)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:445)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
com.hsbc.group.depositproduct.us.svc.activators.RecordProdAppActivator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d1f3f882.recordProdApp(<generated>)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

When I remove this annotation everything works fine. But I don't want to remove this annotation so can some please suggest how to write test here.

2. if I remove @Transactional annotation; I have used @MockBean to mock DAO object(Interface) and its mocking given object but when I try to return expected value for any DAO call its returning default value. Can some one please suggest how to mock DAO while using @MockBean. I have tried @SpyBean, and other possible ways but didn't get success.
   Thanks in advance.